# How to draw a bounding box around detected object in android studio app written in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bounding-box, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

```
val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.strokeWidth = 3f
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        objectDetector.processImage(getVisionImageFromFrame(frame))
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                var result = ""
                it.forEach { item ->
                    val id = item.trackingId
                    val bounds = item.boundingBox
                    val category = item.classificationCategory
                    result +=  category.toString() //TODO : Get the knowledge graph result for this entity
                    Log.e("TAG",category.toString())
                }
                callback(result)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                callback("Unable to detect an object")
            }
            .addOnCompleteListener {

            }
```

Also when the object is being detected a number is being displayed rather than the name of object. For ex: for detecting pen, 010 is being displayed rather than the name "pen". Also I can't get how to draw a bounding box around detected image. Please see to it.

Comment: does it work wirh the codelab?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue yet? I'm currently facing the same problem and came across this question.

Answer (score 1):

You use the google mlkit for object detection, right?! There is a codelab from google in kotlin where they explain the whole implementation process and also how to draw the bounding boxes.

[codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/)

The problem with 010 is that you read out the index number of the category. you have to match it with the category name but this is also in the codelab code. pay attention, there is a difference between [label and category](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/label-images).

Comment: search for "ml kit" on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/